# select works only once

Tags: c, linux, systems-programming

```
   /* Wait up to 1 min */
   tv.tv_sec = 60;
   tv.tv_usec = 0;

   FD_ZERO(&readfd);
   FD_ZERO(&writefd);
   for(i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
     FD_SET(my_rdfd[i], &readfd);
     FD_SET(my_wrfd[i], &writefd);
   }

   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
     retval = select((NRFDS)+1, &readfd, &writefd, (fd_set*)0, &tv);//NRFDS is a macro

     if (retval == -1)
       printf("select() error");
     else if (retval)
     {
       printf("data found\n");
       //do something with the data recieved
     }
     else
       printf("Timeout.\n");
   }
```

The thing is that for the first time select() inside the for loop works as expected, fine, for subsequent loops, it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I suggest to avoid `select(2)` which is becoming obsolete and to use `poll(2)` instead. Notice that `select` may change its timeout.

Comment: But, in select I explicitly specify my timeout in the timeval structure.

Comment: `poll` has a millisecond timeout. Give 6000 ms for 1 minute.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 60000 ms = 1 min

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting this within the for loop:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  tv.tv_sec = 60;
   tv.tv_usec = 0;

   FD_ZERO(&readfd);
   FD_ZERO(&writefd);
   for(j=0;j<3;j++)
   {
     FD_SET(my_rdfd[j], &readfd);
     FD_SET(my_wrfd[j], &writefd);//Note that you should use a different inside forloop
   }

   //select statement here

}
```

When `select()` returns, it changes the sets to show which file descriptors have become ready for read/write/exception. All other flags would have been cleared.

It's important that you re-enable the file descriptors that were cleared prior to starting another select, otherwise, you will no longer be waiting on those file descriptors.

Comment: But, why the FD_ZERO,FD_SET again in for loop?

Comment: @OP: be careful of using the same variable in multiple for loops. I guess you are writing in C++. Check the edited answer for your query.